# Show div when hovering, hide when not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically want to show some extra information below a list of boxes i have, when a box is being hovered over. Each box contains a job, and i need to show a brief job description underneath the row of boxes, when each box is hovered. Here is my HTML so far:

```
<div class="areaBox">
 <div id="area1" class="expertise">Integrated Designers</div>
 <div id="area2" class="expertise">Integrated Designers</div>
 <div id="area3" class="expertise">Digital Account Managers</div>
 <div id="area4" class="expertise">Front End Developers</div>
 <div id="area5" class="expertise">Integrated Designers</div>   
 <div id="area6" class="expertise">Digital Account Managers</div>
 <div id="area7" class="expertise">Front End Developers</div>
 <div id="area8" class="expertise">Integrated Designers</div>
 <div id="area9" class="expertise">Digital Account Managers</div>

 <div id="expertTitle">Integrated Designers-Perfect for those.....etc</div>

</div>
```

So, when someone hovers over "area1", i need the div "expertTitle" to appear below all of the boxes. I have attempted the following:

```
.areabox > #expertTitle{
display:none;
font-family:adelle-sans;
font-size:27px;
color:#ffdc33;
}

.areabox > #area1:hover + #expertTitle{
display:block;
}
```

To no avail. What am i doing wrong here? Should i be using JQuery instead?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the direct sibling css selector (`+`). This will only show if the siblings are directly next to each other in the DOM.

Instead, use the general sibling css selector (`~`). More info on this selector can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

You also have a mismatch between the HTML class name and css selector for "areaBox/areabox".

Here is an example:

```css
.areaBox > #expertTitle{
  display:none;
}

.areaBox > #area1:hover ~ #expertTitle{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="areaBox">
  <div id="area1" class="expertise">Integrated Designers</div>
  <div id="area2" class="expertise">Integrated Designers</div>
  <div id="area3" class="expertise">Digital Account Managers</div>
  <div id="area4" class="expertise">Front End Developers</div>
  <div id="area5" class="expertise">Integrated Designers</div>   
  <div id="area6" class="expertise">Digital Account Managers</div>
  <div id="area7" class="expertise">Front End Developers</div>
  <div id="area8" class="expertise">Integrated Designers</div>
  <div id="area9" class="expertise">Digital Account Managers</div>

  <div id="expertTitle">Integrated Designers-Perfect for those.....etc</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I edited it. I added some JavaScript. Hope this works:

```js
function changeText(text) {
  document.getElementById("expertTitle").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<div class="areaBox">
  <div id="area1" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('Integrated Designers - Perfect for those.....etc');">Integrated Designers</div>
  <div id="area2" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('Yet even more integrated Designers');">Integrated Designers</div>
  <div id="area3" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('Digital stuff - Beep Boup');">Digital Account Managers</div>
  <div id="area4" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('Pepole that are at the front');">Front End Developers</div>
  <div id="area5" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('OMG MORE INTERGATED DESIGNERS!!!');">Integrated Designers</div>
  <div id="area6" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('More digital stuff - beppy boopy');">Digital Account Managers</div>
  <div id="area7" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('YET EVEN MORE Pepole that are at the front');">Front End Developers</div>
  <div id="area8" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('AND YET OMG MORE Integrated Designers OMG OMG OMG');">Integrated Designers</div>
  <div id="area9" class="expertise" onmouseover="changeText('more beep and boopy');">Digital Account Managers</div>
  <hr>
  <div id="expertTitle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, that works for me! Thanks! The issue is now, i have 9 area boxes with 9 different titles of job. How do i get around the issue of printing out 9 different divs, effectively, the text needs to print out in the same space. I have done it the hard way and printed 9 divs out, and positioned them in the right place, but the page adjusts a lot longer for the 9 divs. Is there an easier way to accomplish this. Effectively i need the text to appear in the same div..

Comment: The only way I could think to do this, is to use JavaScript. I will edit my post and add a JavaScript answer.

Comment: There you go. A working JavaScript answer. If you don't want a title to show insert a empty string.